# Get folder and file names and store it in a variable in windows?

Tags: windows, scripting, command-line-interface, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I have a folder `folder1` contain 3 files `file1`, `file2` and `file3`, etc.

I need command line to do the following task.

Store the name of the files in a variable because I want to write a dynamic batch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FOR %%f in (folder1\*) DO @echo %%f
```

in a batch file will echo the filename of each file in the folder. To do the same thing at the command line, use only one percent sign for the variable. You can replace `echo` with some other command.

If you quote the `%%f`, the `echo` will output the quotes around the filename, but if you want to pass the filename to other commands the quotes may be necessary if there are special characters, such as spaces, in the filenames. For example, to output the contents of all the files:

```
FOR %%f in (folder1\*) DO @type "%%f"
```

Without the quotes, if there was a file named "Has Space", `type` would try to output the contents of two files, "Has" and "Space". With the quotes, it will work as intended.

Comment: This works even if file name has spaces in it?

Comment: @SandraK: For many uses you should quote the `%%f` at the end. I've added some additional information to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade from batch to powershell:

```
Foreach ($file in Get-Childitem "<PATH>") {
    $file.name
}

$filenames = (Get-ChildItem -Path "PATH" -Directory).Name
```

Comment: Or simply `gci <path> | select Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in a batch file, you could do it in a for loop like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for %%a in (folder1\*) do (
set fileVariable=%%a
echo !fileVariable!
)
```